# Rails sort by attribute, then specific child attribute in a PG database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting

I am building a forum in Rails 4, and am attempting to implement sticky topic functionality. The sticky attribute (a boolean) is a column in the Topic table. I have some user selectable sorting options, and the default sort is to sort by the latest message's creation time. However, a topic with the sticky attribute should take priority in sorting, so the sticky topics should be listed first, then the topic with the most recent message, then the topic with the second most recent message, etc.

A topic has many messages, and a message belongs to a topic.

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :messages,  -> { order(:created_at) }, dependent: :destroy
  ...
  scope :sort_by_latest_message, -> { includes(:messages).order("messages.created_at DESC") }
  scope :sort_by_sticky, -> { order("sticky DESC") }
  scope :sort_by_created_at, -> { order("created_at DESC") } # This one works, but I'm putting it here for reference.
  ...
end
```

Chaining these two scopes works fine in my development environment, which uses sqlite, but causes an error in production, which uses Postgresql:

> PG::Error: SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select
>   list

I have gathered from StackExchange that this is because the includes(:messages) call has an implicit distinct call, and PG requires the distinct call to be made before any sorting. Reversing the chaining doesn't work because then the sticky attribute takes a backseat to sorting by latest message creation, and I am not sure how to work in the distinct call to the :sort_by_sticky scope, especially when I chain that with :sort_by_created_at.

I have tried using the following as well:

```
  scope :sort_by_latest_message, -> { joins(:messages).group("messages.topic_id").order("messages.created_at DESC") }
```

Which causes an error:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "topics.id" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

I read from other questions and think I might need a select call for that to work, but I am not clear on where that belongs in this situation.

I use a variety of filters based on the params hash, but ultimately, I am trying to get a call like Topic.sort_by_sticky.sort_by_latest_message to work in the PG database. Topic.sort_by_sticky.sort_by_created_at works fine, so my issue seems to be when I want to sort by an attribute on the topic, then an attribute on a child (specifically, the LAST child's created_at value).

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that the original error was primarily occurring when I had applied another filter to filter by tag (a topic has many tags through taggings).

```
  scope :tag_filter, ->(tag_ids) { joins(:tags).where("tag_id IN (?)", tag_ids).uniq }
```

That's from a module included on the Topic model.

However, based on some advice, I have eliminated the :sort_by_latest_message scope and instead created a class method that has similar logic, but always factors in the sticky attribute:

```
    def self.default_sort
      results = self.includes(:messages).sort_by_sticky.order("messages.created_at DESC")
      results
    end
```

I'm actually not clear on how the includes manages to determine that I want to use the *last* message of any topic, but this seems to work. I wasn't sure how to use a hash on the second order call, but I have updated :sort_by_stick_order to use hash notation instead of a string:

```
  scope :sort_by_sticky, -> { order(sticky: :desc) }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have changed my setup a few times since posting this question. At first I used the following methods to achieve sorting by the most recent message, instead of scopes:

```
def self.sort_by_latest_message
  Topic.all.sort_by { |topic| topic.latest_message.created_at }.reverse
end

def latest_message
  messages.sort_by(&:created_at).last
end
```

However that seemed rather inefficient, and I suspected it would gradually become a larger issue with a large number of topics and messages.

So I am currently moving forward to maintaining a latest_message_at column on each topic through the following callback on the Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :topic
  ...
  after_save :update_topic_latest_message_at, on: :create
  ...
  private
    def update_topic_latest_message_at
      self.topic.update_attribute(:latest_message_at, self.created_at) # No validation performed
    end
end
```

Comment: Educated guess, could easily be wrong: I don't think Arel will chain `order` with a text clause. Try `order(sticky: :desc)` and simlar (requires Rails and Arel 4).  Another approach that really ought to work is give up scopes and pass `order()` a hash. See Vitaly's remark at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order on this point.

Comment: This seems to have pointed me in the right direction, and I have updated the original question to reflect the changes I have made. I still have some questions as to how things might work better: how the includes call knows I want the last message of any topic... would it be possible to specify another? And if it's possible to convert order("messages.created_at DESC") to a hash like I have done for :sort_by_sticky. But I have push the changes to production and the error has yet to pop up again. Thank you!

Comment: Usually in Arel, strings and symbols are interchangeable.  So I'd try { 'messages.created' => :desc }  A long shot would be { [messages:, created:] => :desc } or equally long { {messages: :created} => :desc}. But maybe you'll get lucky.